# Which arch linux should I download?

Tags: arch-linux, architecture

I'm going to install Arch linux yet I have to choose between several architectures my computer has.

I have an aluminium macbook pro, with a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5 processor. . The [intel webpage](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processor-comparison/compare-intel-processors.html?fam=corei7) tells me this is a dual core processor.

running `uname -a` in the shell returns:

```
Darwin Romeos-MacBook-Pro.local 11.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0:
Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Which makes me believe I have an `x86_64` machine, yet when executing `arch` in the shell it returns `i386`.

I'm a bit confused about what to pick:

- i686 CPU
- x86-64 CPU
- Dual Architecture

What would you recommend?

Comment: And besides answers here's some info about [Dual Architecture](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=811154#p811154)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel Core 2 (i5) is a 64-bit processor supporting Intel 64, Intel 64 is Intel's implementation of x86-64

Answer (score 2):

You processor supports `x86_64`, so you can choose either a distro compiled for`x86` or `x86_64`.

the `arch` command, reports which architecture your running kernel was compiled for.  It does not show your CPU capabilities.   So you can go either way, I prefer `x86_64`.  I've used `x86_64` from when it was Debian unofficial.  Support has become very mature, you should not have problems going `x86_64`.

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU is x86_64 (Intel Core i5), so either can be used; it's your choice, but I see no reason not to use x86_64.